# CodeIgniter : What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm brand new to CodeIgniter, and I'm trying to execute some simple examples in order to understand how they work. The problem is I'm trying to play with a simple controller to just display a simple view that just says "Index!" in a strong font. I'm also using a `.htaccess` in order to avoid 'index.php' in front of the name of the controller. I'm using mod_rewrite to achieve this. I'm using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

in routes.php I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
```

which tells CodeIgniter that I want to use a controller called `main.php`

which possesses a

Here's my complete controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('main');
}


public function ingrid() {
    $this->load->view('ingrid');
}

public function remote() {
    $this->load->view('remote');
}

}
```

inside it, and should have executed a 'main.php' controller inside views.

Everything appears to be fine but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Main::$load

Filename: controllers/main.php

Line Number: 50

Backtrace:

File: /Users/sam/webroot/voipXX_client_care/application/controllers/main.php
Line: 50
Function: _exception_handler

File: /Users/sam/webroot/voipXX_client_care/index.php
Line: 260
Function: require_once
```

The problem is, I don't understand.

Comment: What hosting service are you using? Are you developing locally? Keep in mind that when trying to remove `index.php` from your URIs by editing your `.htaccess` file varies from hosting service to hosting service. Each hosting service has their own guides on how to do this properly for their servers. That aside, you need to show us all of your controller so that we can see the line where the error is occurring. Show us the controller from top to bottom, please.

Comment: I'm developing locally.
I edited my message above with the complete controller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is probably extending a base Controller right?

Then try to call parent::Controller(); in the constructor of your Main() class.

Comment: `parent::__construct();` for CI

Comment: Yes, it's that. I added the parent::Controller() to the Main controller class and the immediately worked!
What I feel it's strange is that I based my controller from the 'welcome.php' that comes as default when you unzip the downloaded codeigniter and 'welcome.php' does not possesses the construct declaration but it works without that declaration!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your controller as follows:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('main');
    }

    public function ingrid() {
        $this->load->view('ingrid');
    }

    public function remote() {
        $this->load->view('remote');
    }
}
```

Notice I've added:

```
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that! But see my comment to the original message about that I feel strange that the controller that comes originally with the distribution 'welcome.php' does not have the constructor declared and works without problem.